# Are Flexbox and vh height units not compatible in IE11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, viewport-units

I'm trying to use a flexbox-based layout to get a sticky footer for my page. This works well in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE11 the footer sits just after my main content. In other words, the main content isn't stretched to fill all of the available space.

```css
body {
    border: red 1px solid;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
header, footer  {
    background: #dd55dd;
}
main {
    background: #87ccfc;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header role="banner"><h1> .. </h1></header>
    <main role="main">
        <p>.....</p>
    </main>
    <footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

How can I get the main element to stretch in a flex layout when the containers height units are measured in `vh` in IE? I was looking to see if this behaviour is the result of a bug in the way IE implements the flexbox specs, but I couldn't find any mention of this problem elsewhere.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ritchieallen/3tpuryso/)

Answer (score 32):

The issue isn't `vh` units but [`min-height`](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/816293/ie11-flexbox-with-min-height-not-vertically-aligning-with-align-items-center)

I found a semi-working CSS-only solution:

```css
min-height: 100vh;
height: 100px;
```

The extra `height` will enable IE to fill the screen vertically even if the content is not tall enough. The drawback is that IE will no longer wrap the content if it's longer than the viewport.

---

Since this is not enough I made a solution in JS:

## Detection

This function tests the bug: `true` means it's buggy.

```js
function hasBug () {
    // inner should fill outer
    // if inner's height is 0, the browser has the bug

    // set up
    var outer = document.createElement('div');
    var inner = document.createElement('div');
    outer.setAttribute('style', 'display:-ms-flexbox; display:flex; min-height:100vh;');
    outer.appendChild(inner);
    (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(outer);

    // test
    var bug = !inner.offsetHeight;

    // remove setup
    outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

    return bug;
}
```

## Fix

The fix consists of manually setting the `height` of the element in `px`

```js
function fixElementHeight (el) {
    // reset any previously set height
    el.style.height = 'auto'; 

    // get el height (the one set via min-height in vh)
    var height = el.offsetHeight; 

    // manually set it in pixels
    el.style.height = height + 'px'; 
}
```

The element's height will be set to exactly the height of its content. `height` is used as a secondary `min-height` in IE, using the behavior observed in the CSS-only solution.

## Usage

Once those two functions are defined, set it up this way:

```js
if(hasBug()) {
    // fix the element now
    fixElementHeight(el);

    // update the height on resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        fixElementHeight(el);
    });
}
```

## Demo

```js
function hasBug () {
    // inner should fill outer
    // if inner's height is 0, the browser has the bug

    // set up
    var outer = document.createElement('div');
    var inner = document.createElement('div');
    outer.setAttribute('style', 'display:-ms-flexbox; display:flex; min-height:100vh;');
    outer.appendChild(inner);
    (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(outer);

    // test
    var bug = !inner.offsetHeight;

    // remove setup
    outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

    return bug;
}

function fixElementHeight (el) {
    // reset any previously set height
    el.style.height = 'auto'; 

    // get el height (the one set via min-height in vh)
    var height = el.offsetHeight; 

    // manually set it in pixels
    el.style.height = height + 'px'; 
}

var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = hasBug()?'Browser is buggy':'Browser works correctly';


var el = document.getElementById('flex');

if(hasBug()) {
  // fix the element now
  fixElementHeight(el);

  // update the height on resize
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    fixElementHeight(el);
  });
}
```

```css
.half-screen {
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 50vh;

  padding: 10px;
  background: #97cef0;
}


.content {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #b5daf0;
}
```

```html
The inner box should fill the outer box vertically, even if the browser is buggy.
<div class="half-screen" id="flex">
  <div class="content" id="output">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As well as `height:100px` I found adding `overflow-y:auto` to my `main` content area worked fine across all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this same bug yesterday and couldn't solve it by myself either. Unfortunately, seems nothing can be done about it, at the moment, because it's IE bug, which have been reported to the Microsoft developers almost a year ago, here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview

Answer (score 2):

The trick I've found to getting sticky footers working in IE11 is to make sure `flex-basis` is `100%` or even `100vh`. Please see an example below or a [live Codepen example](https://codepen.io/souporserious/pen/PELgXB) that you can test in IE11.

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: seagreen;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

footer {
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
  <p>I will not skateboard in the halls.</p>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @souporserious. However, what actually worked for me was just adding the `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` lines to the `html` CSS element. Adding `flex-basis: 100%` to the `body` CSS element didn't make any difference in IE11, or modern browsers, for that matter.

Answer (score -1):

Usually this helps:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

.. and you don't have to use `vh` units.

Full sample:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  border: red 1px solid;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header,
footer {
  background: #dd55dd;
}
main {
  background: #87ccfc;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Herons - How they plan to eat your eyes!</h1>
</header>
<main>
  Herons are foul and devious birds.
</main>
<footer>
  <small>© 2014 Institute for the prevention of Herons</small>
</footer>
```

Comment: You didn't understand requirement. `body` should occupy at least whole screen, but can take more. This was the purpose of `min-height` here which is buggy in IE.