# Flexbox not filling height in IE11

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have this case:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/radoPd?editors=110

This is the CSS Code:

```
.wrapper{
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar{
  background: orange;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}
.main{
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

For some reason, on IE11, neither the .sidebar nor the .main area will fill the whole height of the wrapper.

This is inconsistency between browsers. Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't have access to IE11 at the moment, so I can only guess. Have you tried explicitly setting `align-items: stretch` on `.wrapper`? Does it react to other values, such as `center` or `flex-end`?

Comment: I tried and that didnt work :( It works with others. I suspect that stretch conflicts somehow with `100vh`

Comment: I don't think that's likely, since `min-height` works on `.wrapper`, while the `align-items` property has an effect on the flex-children, not on the flex-container itself.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177791/ie11-flexbox-and-vh-height-units-not-compatible

Comment: Well… so much for my armchair analysis then :)

Comment: The problem seems to be relative to [here](https://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/): once you set the `min-height` for your wrapper, all children heights are calculated wrong. Solution that worked for me: set `height: 100%`. Unfortunately it may break break FF & Chrome, so you need to apply this CSS from JS conditionally: `isIE11() && $('.wrapper').css('height', '100%');`. But it seem that you have a bit different problem...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This a known [IE bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview) that unfortunately has been closed as `Won't Fix` by IE Team and described as follows:

> In all other browsers that support flexbox, a `flex-direction:column` based flex container will honor the containers `min-height` to calculate `flex-grow` lengths. In IE10 & 11-preview it only seems to work with an explicit `height` value.

AFAIK and despite this description, the bug also applies when `flex-direction` is `row`. As mentioned in the comments Philip Walton has proposed a solution [here](https://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/), which includes setting height to a fixed value, but this is not an option for OP.

As a workaround I propose to set a `min-height: 100vh` to the `main` element too:

```
.wrapper{
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar{
  background: orange;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}
.main{
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Pen [here](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/ayKyoa).

Comment: Is there a generic solution when the wrapper is not `100vh`?  I have a "table" made of divs, and simply want each column cell in a row to be the same height.  So I have `display:flex` on the `row` div, and this creates desired behavior in Chrome, but in IE if one cell has lots of content, and an adjacent cell has little content, the cell with little content does not stretch vertically to be the same height as the cell with lots of content.

Comment: Display: table?